# Prevent text wrapping on email - outlook 2007+

Tags: css, html-table, html-email, email, outlook-2007

I made a php script that generate and send emails with some statistics.

It works well but i have a tiny problem with my table.

Sometimes my columns are too "thin" and the content  breaks into multiple lines like this :

[image: example]

i want to prevent this behavior.

I have tried two solutions :

white-space : nowrap; > doesnt work in outlook 2007

working with min-width >  doesnt work in outlook 2007

Is there another solution that would work in outlook ?

Thanks

Comment: Can't you just make a fixed width= on each cell? 
Like e.g. 40% , 20%, 10%, 20%, 10%.
And then make sure you have enough space for all the letters? Otherwise make the font-size a bit smaller, or the mail larger :)

Answer (score 3):

Please use HTML  nowrap Attribute
When present, it specifies that the content inside a cell should not wrap.

Sample usage

```
<td nowrap>Not Found!</td>
```

References:
 1. [w3.org](https://www.w3.org/MarkUp/html3/tablerows.html)
 2. [w3schools](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_td_nowrap.asp)

***Note:*** Praveen Innocent answer is good but I don't have enough reputation to add comments

Comment: @JohanKarlsson, Thanks. useful to keep in mind but In my context, like the one of the question I believe for the moment we can still avoid HTML5 in Email body, isn't right?

Answer (score 0):

Using a nowrap on your  prevents the text in td from breaking into multiple lines.

Eg: Doing `<td nowrap> 10.9.6.80 </td>` should solve your problem.

Some source: [w3school](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_td_nowrap.asp)

Comment: Could you give some more details?